# How to reset css (a:visited{color:green}) when refresh browser address bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have successfully tested visited link effect on a tag for XHTML document.
But those visited link highlight with green color could not removed when I refresh the
address bar on my browser except I click  clear up all  browser cache and history on every browser. So  the question is how to reset all css  when click browser refresh button without clear up browser cache and history ?

So for my site I need to do something with php code to delete all cookie or history  about those site I visited , Right ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
<style>
#checkvisited{width:730px;margin-left:0px;}
#checkvisited  td a{text-decoration:none;color:gray;}
#checkvisited td a:link{color:gray}
#checkvisited td a:hover{text-decoration:underline}
#checkvisited td  a:active{background-color:#DEB887}
#checkvisited td  a:visited{color:green}
</style>
</head>
<body><div id='checkvisited'>
<table><td><a href="http://yahoo.com" >AA</a></td><td><a href="http://yahoo.com?  a=1">BB</a></td>
</table></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "visited" link, i.e. one that gets picked up by the `:visited` pseudo-class, is one that is in the browser's history. So, the only way to turn those links back into non-visited links is to remove them from the browser's history.

Incidentally you don't need your `a:link` definition. `:link` is for highlighting non-visited links. Seeing as you have a base definition for `a` and a definition for `a:visited`, your `a:link` is redundant.

Here, however, is a proposed solution intended to defend against an attacker discovering a user's browser history by using `getComputedClass` to reveal all visited links in a page:

http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy

(Almost certainly what you are looking for, but it's useful reading on the mechanics of `:visited` nonetheless)

Comment: It's possible for an `a` element to be neither `:link` nor `:visited` (i.e. *not a link*), so it isn't entirely redundant. Since the common convention is to have both pseudo-classes (they are equally specific, anyway), there is no reason to take out the `:link` if it's already there.

Comment: Why you said it is redundant, :link is for non-visited link and :visited is for visited link ?

Comment: I said it was redundant because `a` applies a style to all `<a>` (including visited) and `a:visited` applies a style to visited links only; the difference being links that have not been visited, which can also be (redundantly) addressed with `:link`. The edge-case that BoltClock has identified is where you have `<a>` without a `href` attribute. Those would not be picked up by `:link`.

Comment: Why I can not use , getComputedStyle(document.links[i], ":visited").color, to get all visited color ? it always show the normal un-visited color

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add a randomizer to the end of href attributes of you link on page load. This way, when your page reloads, the link href is different since it has a new random value at the end.

```
// lets say, this is your link
var link = document.getElementById('foo');

// suffix a randomizer to the href attribute
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
var href = link.getAttribute('href');
link.setAttribute('href', href + (href.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + '_=' + rand);
```

*Note:* This will be useful only if the link opens in another tab/window or if it is an in-page link. Otherwise, clicking the link anyway takes the user to another page.

Comment: if I get confusing about doing that, how :visited css works for those visited site if the href is not unqiue  or  is random ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of different color of a:visited, i use this:

```
a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
```

If this was asked.