# Reset all visited site color for default color css setting for all latest browser and all doctype(xhtml,html, html5)

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website user ask why those his visited link on my site is always recorded even he
logout and login my site again. And that is of course, I could NOT request users to
do browser history clear up every time they re-visit my site

So I want mysite css can be back to normal setting as non-visited link and css after
user logout and login again. Is it possible ?
I have read several question and reply on stackflow.com that told me

[How can I detect visited and unvisited links on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290959/how-can-i-detect-visited-and-unvisited-links-on-a-page)

[How to reset css (a:visited{color:green}) when refresh browser address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439900/how-to-reset-css-avisitedcolorgreen-when-refresh-browser-address-bar)

it is impossible by Browser security and privacy concern

When I follow this link, http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy, the code 
said it will be able to get back those visited link color. But after doing that,
it will always report to me all link with as un-visited link color. Why ? 
Is it again browser security and privacy issue ?

```
var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
var link = links[i];
/* exact strings to match actually need to be
   auto-detected using reference elements */
if (getComputedStyle(link, "").color == "rgb(0, 0, 128)") {
    // we know link.href has not been visited
} else {
    // we know link.href has been visited
}
}
```

So my question is "could I recover my visited-link color as un-visited link color  after
logout and login mysite or refresh browser address bar button for latest browser? How ?

If using HTML5, it will be possible ?

Or do  I tell my users that is impossible to reset css except clear up browser history ?

Comment: That happens on for all sites and since the data is stored locally you can't manipulate it. sry.

Comment: so, it happen as usual as other website, like bank, schools, forum,etc for latest browsers. If so, I just reply my users it is impossible except clear up browser history. Right ?

Comment: yes, it does. But not all of them have a css selector for :visited

Comment: What you mean, css selector? Could you write more ?

Comment: Have a look at my answer below. Posted an example as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens for all sites and since the data is stored locally you can't manipulate it. Sry.

If you really want to get rid of it remove the :visited selector from your links in your CSS.

That means if you have a selector like

```
a:visited {color: red;}
```

you want to remove the entire rule. That way they won't be shown different than normal links anymore.

Comment: How to do it ? Could you give me a simple example ?

Comment: So there are none left in your CSS? You might want to refresh your browser (delete cache) to see the effect.

Comment: Of course, I have such a:visited{color:red}, otherwise why my users will complaint the link is always recorded as visited link even they logout and login mysite becoz the browser record down those link visited

Comment: Remove it from your CSS.

Comment: If I removed it , how users will be aware the site is visited after they clicked the links ?

Comment: Thats your only choice.

Comment: What I want , for first time visit, the link visited by user will change from normal green to red, and then when users quit browser OR logout and login again, all link will recover to be green

Comment: So you answer is impossible except everytime clear up browser history, Right ?

Comment: Remove the CSS we talked about and have it clean. Otherwise you will have to live with the issue you describe.

Comment: Or I don't give the visited color feature to my users that will solve my question, Right ?

Comment: In other words, just let the link always be un-visited with green color

Comment: So no visited feature anymore , Right ?

Comment: exactly. Its not really necessary anyways.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20440072/100342) you received to your last question was correct.

You as the site owner cannot make a link in your visitors' browser "unvisited". The only thing you *could* do is change the link.

Comment: The only thing you could do is change the link, What you mean ? If so, that might save my work, just reply them it is impossible except clear up browser history